# Tweets with Coordinates Tweepy python

Tags: python, json, tweepy

I am trying to use Streaming Api of twitter and tweepy to get some tweets  filtered by some keywords(already done) and their coordinates which I can later plot on google map. However i am getting an error when I am executing the following code to store only those tweets where coordinates are not null.

Code:

```
def on_data(self, data):

    json_object = json.loads(data)
    if (json_object["user"]["coordinates"]!="null"):
        f.write(data)
```

After some time I get an error that says

> `Key error:user`

Can anybody tell me the reason why this error happened and what steps can be taken to resolve or understand this error better.

Answer (score 3):

You are getting this error because its not necessary all the tweets will have the `user` field.

```
def on_data(self, data):
    json_object = json.loads(data)
    # next statement will short circuit if 'user' field is not found.
    if "user" in json_object and "coordinates" in json_object["user"] and json_object["user"]["coordinates"]!="null":
        f.write(data)
```

Or if you want to do this gracefully -

```
def on_data(self, data):
    try:
        if json_object["user"]["coordinates"]!="null":
            f.write(data)
    except:
        pass
```

Comment: then how can i make the program skip those in which there is no coordinates feilds?

Comment: You should be aware of the other message types. [DOC](https://dev.twitter.com/streaming/overview/messages-types)